# SQL query use to return latest ID from mysql database, not it returns 99999

Tags: java, mysql, sql

My server would retrieve the latest ID from the database, now it is stuck and keeps returning the id `99999`, even though the latest id is now `100040`

My code is:

```
String insertTable = "SELECT * FROM dutyofcare ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 1";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertTable);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
String ResultS = "";
if (rs.next()) {
    ResultS += rs.getString("Id");
}
```

Comment: Yes, because it is doing a lexical sort, not a numeric one. I'm guessing your ID column is of char type?

Comment: it worked from 1-99999, how to I change it that it will return the latest ID?

Comment: It is varchar, what is the best way to fix this? should I change it to int?

Comment: Why is it a varchar, when you clearly store numbers in it? Also instead of doing a convoluted query like that, why not use `SELECT MAX(id) FROM dutyofcare`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `ORDER BY` in your query is doing a lexical (character-by-character) sort where 9 *always* comes after 1, and not numeric sort which handles the digit positions. This is because of the column type of ID. What you need is to ensure ID is a number before the sort is done.

Either change your ID to a numeric column type and run below query:

`SELECT MAX(ID) from dutyofcare;`

Or if you want to retain your column type (less efficient than above option):

`select MAX(cast(ID AS UNSIGNED)) from dutyofcare;`

Or if you want to retain your column type AND just fix your existing query (least efficient of all the options)

`select * from dutyofcare order by CAST(ID AS UNSIGNED) desc limit 1;`

All these methods basically treat the ID as number and choose the biggest value.

Comment: Great just what I needed, now that I understand that it is ordered by a lexical sort, it makes sense.